# No Bluetooth Found on ubuntu 22.04 for ASUS laptop

Tags: bluetooth

I install ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop (Vivobook-ASUSLaptop-X1502ZA-R1502ZA). When I want to turn on the Bluetooth from settings, I got the "No Bluetooth Found" message. I tried different solutions but got nothing.
I ran `sudo service bluetooth status` and got:

```
○ bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
    Active: inactive (dead)
      Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

Also, this is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; sudo dmesg | grep -i blue`:

```
0000:02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
     DeviceName: WLAN
     Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0809]
     Kernel driver in use: rtw_8821ce
     Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce
10000:e0:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0 [8086:464d] (rev 04)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**Update**

When I ran the following command:

```
sudo modprobe btusb
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo systemctl start Bluetooth
```

Get these outputs for the `sudo dmesg | grep -i blue`

```
[ 2069.155398] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[ 2069.155464] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[ 2069.155466] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 2069.155473] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 2069.155476] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 2069.155480] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 2083.926023] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 2083.926025] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 2083.926028] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Output of the last command is incomplete.

Comment: That's all what I got. @Pilot6

Comment: `lsusb` doesn't show a USB BT device, so trying to start `btusb` is useless. The debvice is either disabled in BIOS, or is using some other interface. Most likely it is not supported by Ubuntu kernels. You can report a bug by `ubuntu-bug linux`. Try to install the latest mainline kernel and check if it is supported there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for a couple of weeks now. what worked for me is to power-off the computer entirely, even removing the power cable for a while and then turning it back on. Based on this thread:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1859592/comments/2

In your case since it's a laptop you might need to remove the battery.